# Kotlin: How apply all list elements to the object?

Tags: kotlin, refactoring

I have such kotlin code. I didn't write it very elegantly, but it works correctly.
How can I write this more beautifully using kotlin tools?

I need to apply all elements from the `filters` list to the `query` object.

```kotlin
fun create(filters: List<FilterFactory.Filter>, searchQuery: SearchQuery): Query {
    var query = Query()
    filters.forEach { filter -> query = filter.apply(query) }

    return query
}
```

Comment: To be fair: while there may be a little room for improvement, that code is already very clear, straightforward, easy to understand, neat, and fairly concise. I've seen _far_ worse code than that (sometimes in production systems)…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor the implementation of the function by using [fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) here:

```kotlin
fun create(filters: List<FilterFactory.Filter>): Query =
    filters.fold(Query()) { q, f -> f.apply(q) }
```

Note that your initial code didn't make use of the `searchQuery` parameter, so I removed it.

As for the API, you might want to use an extension function instead, with the `toX()` convention for the name. For instance:

```kotlin
fun List<FilterFactory.Filter>.toQuery(): Query =
    fold(Query()) { q, f -> f.apply(q) }
```

`toQuery()` on a list of filters might be confusing to some, though. Maybe a better approach would be an extension on `Query` itself:

```kotlin
fun Query.withFilters(filters: List<FilterFactory.Filter>): Query =
    filters.fold(this) { q, f -> f.apply(q) }
```

Then to use it you'll need to provide the initial `Query` instance on the call site:

```kotlin
val filteredQuery = Query().withFilters(filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is a simple `apply` call to configure the object you've created:

```
fun create(filters: List<FilterFactory.Filter>, searchQuery: SearchQuery): Query {
    return Query().apply { 
        filters.forEach { filter -> filter.apply(this) }
    }
}
```

which lends itself nicely to the single-expression style

```
fun create(filters: List<FilterFactory.Filter>, searchQuery: SearchQuery) =
    Query().apply { 
        filters.forEach { filter -> filter.apply(this) }
    }
```

(I'm assuming you're using `searchQuery` in there somewhere, e.g. the `Query` constructor)

Comment: Mmh this assumes `filter.apply(query)` actually mutates the query object. Given OP's original code, I don't think we can assume this. But I don't know the API used here so maybe it's fine

Comment: @Joffrey ohhh you're right, I completely missed `query` was being reassigned in the `forEach`. Yeah it has to be the `fold` - I'll delete this in a bit. Thanks!